# Get title, meta description content using URL

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I am trying to extract title and meta tag's description content from a URL, this is what I have:

```
fin[] //urls in a string array

for (int f = 0; f < fin.length; f++)
{
Document finaldoc = Jsoup.connect(fin[f]).get(); //fin[f] contains url at each instance
Elements finallink1 = finaldoc.select("title");
out.println(finallink1);
Elements finallink2 = finaldoc.select("meta");
out.println(finallink2.attr("name"));
out.println(fin[f]); //printing url at last
}
```

but it is not printing the title, and simply prints description as "description" and prints the url.

result :

`description
plus.google.com
generator
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/google
description
earth.google.com`

Answer (score 20):

You can use this:

```
String getMetaTag(Document document, String attr) {
    Elements elements = document.select("meta[name=" + attr + "]");
    for (Element element : elements) {
        final String s = element.attr("content");
        if (s != null) return s;
    }
    elements = document.select("meta[property=" + attr + "]");
    for (Element element : elements) {
        final String s = element.attr("content");
        if (s != null) return s;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then:

```
 String title = document.title();
 String description = getMetaTag(document, "description");
 if (description == null) {
    description = getMetaTag(document, "og:description");
 }
 // and others you need to
 String ogImage = getMetaTag(document, "og:image")
```

....

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the title is not a meta tag, and can be accessed in jsoup by: `document.title()`

Comment: Additionally, you could call your method with "og:description" if nothing is found for "description": getMetaTag(document, "og:description");

Comment: Thanks for this. The relevant imports, since there are a lot of 'Element' in java:

```import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```