# extract title, description and h1 form a url using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract the Title, description, H1 from a url in JAVA.
i try the example here [Get title, meta description content using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958425/get-title-meta-description-content-using-url) but it pop-out an error: non-static method getMetaTag(org.jsoup.nodes.Document,java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Does anyone now why?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the method getMetaTag is not static and you are trying to call it directly from a static method. 
 An instance member can't be called directly by a static member 
 See it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html 
 Edit: Try to instantiate the class.

```
new YourClass().getMetaTag();
```