# How to get page meta (title, description, images) like facebook attach url using Regex in java

Tags: jsoup

How to get page meta (title, description, images) like facebook attach url using Regex in .java

Comment: Hi, I need to get description of a page asap.. can anyone help me..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958425/get-title-meta-description-content-using-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get title, meta description content using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958425/get-title-meta-description-content-using-url)

Comment: -1: no effort in what you've tried so far, basically you ask the community to do a thing for you. This question could be considered historical, but should not be considered as example of good question.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a snippet that reads a web page and builds a little chunk of HTML that will display the Open Graph image, and Title to the right wrapping around the image.  It falls back to using just html title if OG tags are missing, so it can work to represent all web pages.

```
public static String parsePageHeaderInfo(String urlStr) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Connection con = Jsoup.connect(urlStr);

    /* this browseragant thing is important to trick servers into sending us the LARGEST versions of the images */
    con.userAgent(Constants.BROWSER_USER_AGENT);
    Document doc = con.get();

    String text = null;
    Elements metaOgTitle = doc.select("meta[property=og:title]");
    if (metaOgTitle!=null) {
        text = metaOgTitle.attr("content");
    }
    else {
        text = doc.title();
    }

    String imageUrl = null;
    Elements metaOgImage = doc.select("meta[property=og:image]");
    if (metaOgImage!=null) {
        imageUrl = metaOgImage.attr("content");
    }

    if (imageUrl!=null) {
        sb.append("<img src='");
        sb.append(imageUrl);
        sb.append("' align='left' hspace='12' vspace='12' width='150px'>");
    }

    if (text!=null) {
        sb.append(text);
    }

    return sb.toString();       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clay.  It helped me to solve the same issue in Swift for iOS

Answer (score 6):

As Ishikawa Yoshi mentioned, use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org)

Example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get()
for(Element meta : doc.select("meta")) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + meta.attr("name") + " - Content: " + meta.attr("content"));
}
```

This code is untested, hope this helps.

Using RegEx for scraping a document is a bad idea, read about it [on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Answer (score 3):

How about this? 
Below statement parse all tags start with "og:".
It's useful.

> doc.select("meta[property^=og:]")

```
void parseOGTag(String response) {
    // Parse og tags
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
    Elements ogTags = doc.select("meta[property^=og:]");
    if (ogTags.size() <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Set OGTags you want
    String title;
    String desc;
    String image;
    for (int i = 0; i < ogTags.size(); i++) {
        Element tag = ogTags.get(i);

        String text = tag.attr("property");
        if ("og:image".equals(text)) {
            image = tag.attr("content");
        } else if ("og:description".equals(text)) {
            desc = tag.attr("content");
        } else if ("og:title".equals(text)) {
            title = tag.attr("content");
        }
    }                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) to get a `Document` object, then use something like the below method to get tags for each property I'm looking for.

```
String findTag(Document document, String property) {
    String tag = null;
    String cssQuery = "meta[property='og:" + property + "']";
    Elements elements = document.select(cssQuery);

    if (elements != null && elements.size() >= 1) {
        tag = elements.first().attr("content");
    }
    return tag;
}
```

I used this often enough to where I decided to combine the fetching (with JSOUP) and parsing together into a library called [ogmapper](https://github.com/iumehara/ogmapper).