# Get short description part from Google search results

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I use jsoup HTML parser to filter URLs. I would like to get also short descriptions from result lists, like this:

> Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the
>   Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel
>   Spolsky, as a more open ...

You can see above URL filtering method.

```
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

        String temp = link.attr("href");        
        if(temp.startsWith("/url?q=")){
                            //use regex to get domain name
            result.add(getDomainName(temp));
        }

    }
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us the relevant html.

Comment: An example: https://www.google.hu/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=MuFIVdPCJ6-t8weLnoAY&gws_rd=ssl#q=stackoverflow&spell=1

Comment: That part is just not included in the html source. Looks like its mostly javascript and Jsoup does not support javascript.

Comment: But it get out urls and titles great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the meta description for what appears in the google results.

This question is what you are looking for: 
[Get title, meta description content using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958425/get-title-meta-description-content-using-url)

or specifically, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958448/4807777

Comment: But how to store these or how to print these out?

Comment: The getMetaTag method returns a string. Simplest print: System.out.println , or a logger. For storage you can use XML or JSON if you don't want the results in a database. Google how to write json in java or whatever you decide upon.